# Django and HTMX for dynamically updating dropdown list in form.field

Tags: django, htmx

Using django and htmx I need to do the following. In a parent form `create-update.html` I need to give a user the
ability to add another 'contact' instance to a field that contains a drop list of all current 'contact'
instances in the database. I want the user to click an add button next to the `sro.form` field, which renders a modal
containing a child form `new_contact.html`. The user will then enter the new 'contact' instance into the child
form in the modal form `new_contact.html` and click save. This will cause the new contact instance to be saved to
the database via `create_contact_view()`, and for the the `sro` form field in the parent form `create-update.html`
to be replaced via an AJAX call, with an refreshed dropdown list I've partially completed this. I have a working
modal form which is saving new 'contact' instances to the database, but the `sro.form` field just disappears and isn't
reloaded. Here's my code. Many thanks.

views.py

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectUpdateForm
    template_name = "create-update.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["type"] = "Project"
        context["new_contact_url"] = reverse("register:new-contact")  # to create new url
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        mode = form.cleaned_data["mode"]
        if mode is None:
            form.add_error("mode", "This field is required")
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)
        
def create_contact_view(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    url = reverse("register:new-contact")  # to create method
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "url": url,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        context['form'] = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, "partials/hx_new_contact.html", context)
    return render(request, "new_contact.html", context)
```

create-update.html

```
    <div class="form-group">
                <form method="POST" novalidate> {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}

                            {%  if not form.instance.pk %}
                                {{ form.mode|as_crispy_field}}
                            {% endif %}

                            {{ form.gov_tier|as_crispy_field }}
                            {{ form.group|as_crispy_field }}

                            {% include 'partials/hx_new_contact.html' %}

                            {{ form.pd|as_crispy_field }}
                            {{ form.pmo|as_crispy_field }}

                            {{ form.description|as_crispy_field }}


                    <br><input class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" value="Save"/>
                </form>
            </div>
```

partials/hx_new_contact.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div id="modals-here">


    {{ form.sro|as_crispy_field }}

<button
        hx-get="{{ new_contact_url }}"
        hx-target="#modals-here"
        hx-trigger="click"
        hx-swap="innerHTML"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        _="on htmx:afterOnLoad wait 10ms then add .show to #modal then add .show to
        #modal-backdrop">Add Contact</button>
</div>
```

new_contact.html

```
<div id="modal-backdrop" class="modal-backdrop fade show" style="display:block;"></div>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" style="display:block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">New Contact</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <form action="." method="POST" hx-post="{% if url %}{{ url }}{% else %}.{% endif %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="closeModal()">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
function closeModal() {
    var container = document.getElementById("modals-here")
    var backdrop = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop")
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal")

    modal.classList.remove("show")
    backdrop.classList.remove("show")

    setTimeout(function() {
        container.removeChild(backdrop)
        container.removeChild(modal)
    }, 200)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your modal container should be somewhere at the end of your `body`, not in your form, so move that div to the bottom of the page.

###### hx_new_contact.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div id="contact-input-container"> <!-- make a <div id="modals-here"></div> at the end of the <body> and rename this div #contact-input-container -->
    {{ form.sro|as_crispy_field }}
    <button
            hx-get="{{ new_contact_url }}"
            hx-target="#modals-here"
            hx-trigger="click"
            hx-swap="innerHTML"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            _="on htmx:afterOnLoad wait 10ms then add .show to #modal then add .show to
            #modal-backdrop">Add Contact
    </button>
</div>
```

---

###### new_contact.html

In your this modal, you forgot to set the `hx-target` and `hx-swap` attributes, so the form replaced itself in your example, then you hide the modal, that's why you don't see any change.

```
<div id="modal-backdrop" class="modal-backdrop fade show" style="display:block;"></div>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" style="display:block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">New Contact</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- ADD hx-target and hx-swap attributes to your form -->
        <form 
            action="." 
            method="POST" 
            hx-post="{% if url %}{{ url }}{% else %}.{% endif %}"
            hx-target="#contact-input-container" 
            hx-swap="outerHTML" 
        >

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="closeModal()">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
function closeModal() {
    var container = document.getElementById("modals-here")
    var backdrop = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop")
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal")

    modal.classList.remove("show")
    backdrop.classList.remove("show")

    setTimeout(function() {
        container.removeChild(backdrop)
        container.removeChild(modal)
    }, 200)
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for such a quick response. That works! The sro.form element is now being replaced. However the create-update.html page is freezing and needs to be refreshed for all form elements to work.

Comment: What do you mean by freezing? What is the output of the console?

Comment: I'm getting the console error message 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.'

Comment: Apologies I have worked out what was going wrong. I had inadvertently wrapped all html in `new.contact.hmtl` inside another <div id="modals-here"></div>, in addition to placing <div id="modals-here"></div> in the body. This was throwing the error. Everything works just fine now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I have one further question...! I'm using a third party library `easy_select2` /  `Select2` to render the `sro.form` drop-down selection box nicely. But, the form widgets are not being served via the htmx partial render and I'm left with a basic Django multi-selection box. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think it's better to post another question so other people can also help.

Comment: I've asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920066/refresh-django-form-widgets-using-htmx. Thank you.